# Clearing theme cache

Tags: caching

I added new code to the template.php and tried clearing the cache but it does not seem like the cache is being cleared. I tried the Admin ->settings->performance and drush (not sure if I installed it properly). Would there be any suggestions?

Drupal 6.

Comment: How do you know that the cache isn't being cleared? If your new code isn't being recognized, perhaps it's an issue with your code?

Comment: Can you get a simple message to show up with drupal_set_message()? As for drush, do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the new code that you've added to the template.php file? When I run into problems like this, in the 95% of cases I make a mistake and the cache clearing works, but my new code won't be recognized because of errors.

Basically, if you're able to run

```
drush cc all
```

without any warnings or errors, the cache clearing succeed and it should tell you that

```
'all' cache was cleared [success]
```